# Ошибка ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть проблема при использовании библиотек Pandas и Matlotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfr = pd.read_csv('./troinik2.csv', low_memory=False, delimiter=';', decimal=',')
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': dfr[['ModelingTime']],
                   'y': dfr[['P']]}, index=[0])
df=df.astype(float)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

вот код ошибки:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kiber/PycharmProjects/untitled14/ppp.py", line 7, in <module>
    df=df.astype(float)
  File "C:\Users\kiber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5698, in astype
    new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\kiber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 582, in astype
    return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\kiber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 442, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kiber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 625, in astype
    values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
  File "C:\Users\kiber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 897, in astype_nansafe
    return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе полный error traceback и желательно пример данных, который поможет воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: @MaxU код ошибки в описании

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю проблема в том как вы создаете `df` - в качестве значений столбцов `x` и `y` вы указываете DataFrame вместо столбцов.

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\troinik2.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", index_col=0)

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня выходит ошибка в графике. Там выходит ровный график

Comment: @kiber, можете выложить "troinik2.csv" на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/edit/disk/disk%2F%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0.xlsx?sk=y8ff8e0f56026a08f87b700a746d2cecc

Comment: https://transfiles.ru/h3cjr

Comment: можете пожалуйста выложить весь ваш код?

Comment: @kiber, выложил __весь__ свой код)

Comment: нет можно прямо весь код полностью с импортами и всем остальным. я просто запутался)

Comment: я вот прямо АБСОЛЮТНО ВЕСЬ код со всеми импортами привел в ответе - больше просто нет :) Вы его проюовали запустить? Что-то не работает?

Comment: большое вам спасибо!!!!!!!! все работает

Comment: задание выполнено